# How to compare two elements of a list to find lowest price?

Tags: python, algorithm, list

Given two lists `avail` and `prod`, with `avail` being a list that contains a phone number, item code and price, and `prod` being a list that contains item code and name, I want to try and find the lowest price for the given item code if the item code in `avail` is also in `prod` (product list), returning a list of lists that provides the phone number, price, and item code for each item.

I've tried the code below but it just appends each `j[2]` understandably (it appends all prices and just prints the min). I don't know how to implement this.

```py
def best_prices(avail,prod):
    lowest_prices=[]
    price_list=[]
    for i in prod:
        for j in avail:
            if i[0]==j[1]:
                price_list.append(j[2])
                store_min=min(price_list)
                print(store_min)
                print(price_list)
                lowest_prices.append(j)
    return lowest_prices
```

The lists are in this format:

```py
avail = [
    ['phone number', 'item code', 'price'],
    ...
] 

prod = [
    ['item code', 'name of product'],
    ...
]
```

Here are some input samples:

```py
prod = [
    ['123456789', '2L 2% Vitali Milk'],
    ['123456798', '1L 2% Vitali Milk'],
    ['456392452', '70% Cocoa Zimbra Chocolate'],
    ['456123490', 'Zimbra Milk Chocolate'],
    ['634590221', 'Onion flavour chips'],
    ['634599011', 'Vinegar flavour chips'],
    ['780123678', 'Sliced white bread'],
    ['780432109', 'Sliced whole wheat bread'],
    ['809001234', '2L Orange Juice'],
    ['808765432', '2L Apple Juice']
]

avail = [
    ['123456789', '7807890123', '2.58'],
    ['123456789', '7804922860', '2.99'],
    ['456392452', '7807890123', '2.11'],
    ['456123490', '7804922860', '3.10'],
    ['808765432', '7809876543', '4.10']
]
```

I want to my program to for every matching item code, look through `avail` to find the lowest price and then return a list containing phone number of lowest price lowest price and item code.

So, for:

```py
prod = [
    ['123456789', '2L 2% Vitali Milk']
]
```

and

```py
avail = [
    ['123456789', '7807890123', '2.58'],
    ['123456789', '7804922860', '2.99'],
    ['456392452', '7807890123', '2.11']
]
```

I want to return:

```py
new_list = [
    ['2.58', '123456789', '7807890123']
]
```

Comment: Please provide a sample input and output to help make your question more clear

Comment: A first step would be to combine your two lists into one. Then indeed `min` should immediately return the right values.

Comment: @G.Anderson Done added a sample case

Comment: @usr2564301 How would that work though? I want to return a list of lists containing price, item code, phone number for each list in the list of lists. So one for each item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an answer with explanation in the comments:

```
prod = [
    ['123456789', '2L 2% Vitali Milk'],
    ['123456798', '1L 2% Vitali Milk'],
    ['456392452', '70% Cocoa Zimbra Chocolate'],
    ['456123490', 'Zimbra Milk Chocolate'],
    ['634590221', 'Onion flavour chips'],
    ['634599011', 'Vinegar flavour chips'],
    ['780123678', 'Sliced white bread'],
    ['780432109', 'Sliced whole wheat bread'],
    ['809001234', '2L Orange Juice'],
    ['808765432', '2L Apple Juice']
]
avail = [
    ['123456789', '7807890123', '2.58'],
    ['123456789', '7804922860', '2.99'],
    ['456392452', '7807890123', '2.11'],
    ['456123490', '7804922860', '3.10'],
    ['808765432', '7809876543', '4.10']
]

# you can keep track of the best record for a given product code using a dict
result = {}

# since prod is really just a mapping from product code to product name, it 
# also works well as a dict
prod_d = {p[0]: p[1] for p in prod}

# now, it's easy to construct the result from avail:
# (the cast to tuple allows for spreading into nicely named variables)
for pc, phone, price in (tuple(a) for a in avail):
    # using -1 as price will still be the last element
    if pc not in result or price < result[pc][-1]:
        result[pc] = [prod_d[pc], phone, price]
print(result)

# if you prefer a list after all:
result = [[pc, prod, phone, price] for pc, (prod, phone, price) in result.items()]
print(result)
```

Result:

```
{'123456789': ['2L 2% Vitali Milk', '7807890123', '2.58'], '456392452': ['70% Cocoa Zimbra Chocolate', '7807890123', '2.11'], '456123490': ['Zimbra Milk Chocolate', '7804922860', '3.10'], '808765432': ['2L Apple Juice', '7809876543', '4.10']}
[['123456789', '2L 2% Vitali Milk', '7807890123', '2.58'], ['456392452', '70% Cocoa Zimbra Chocolate', '7807890123', '2.11'], ['456123490', 'Zimbra Milk Chocolate', '7804922860', '3.10'], ['808765432', '2L Apple Juice', '7809876543', '4.10']]
```

Just the solution:

```
result = {}
prod_d = {p[0]: p[1] for p in prod}

for pc, phone, price in (tuple(a) for a in avail):
    if pc not in result or price < result[pc][-1]:
        result[pc] = [prod_d[pc], phone, price]

result_list = [[pc, prod, phone, price] for pc, (prod, phone, price) in result.items()]
```

Comment: Note that you can easily change what you want in the resulting sub-lists by moving the elements around or leaving some of them out, matter of preference and what you need the lists for.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, clear and quite pythonic solution of your problem below.

I made an assumption that price is always at the last position in the `avail` list and item code is always at the first position in the both `avail` and `prod` list. It's rather obvious, but be careful with lists' elements order.

**Solution:**

```
avail = [
    ['item code', 'phone number', 'price'],
    ...
]

prod = [
    ['item code', 'name of product'],
    ...
]

def best_prices(avail, prod):
    # find only items from available with item code present in products
    items = [
        av for av in avail if any(av[0] == pr[0] for pr in prod)
    ]
    # check if any item is available
    if not items:
       return None
    # sort items by price (ascending) and return first item
    return sorted(items, key=lambda x: x[2])[0]
```

**Example:**

```
>>> prod = [
...     ['123456789', '2L 2% Vitali Milk'],
... ]
>>> avail = [
...     ['123456789', '7807890123', '2.58'],
...     ['123456789', '7804922860', '2.99'],
...     ['456392452', '7807890123', '2.11'],
... ]
>>> print(best_prices(avail, prod))
['123456789', '7807890123', '2.58']
```

If elements order of returned list is really important for you (but I don't think so), you can reorder (reverse) it:

```
def best_prices(avail, prod):
    ....
    return sorted(items, key=lambda x: x[2])[0][::-1]
```

**Bonus:**

Extreme one-liner which works exactly as you expect it to work:

```
>>> print((sorted([a for a in avail if any(a[0] == p[0] for p in prod)], key=lambda x: x[2]) or [None])[0][::-1])
['2.58', '7807890123', '123456789']
```

*Disclaimer: it is probably not a good idea to use such one-liners in your code.*

Comment: @MattTheWizard changed his question after I published my answer (order of lists' elements changed) so I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First advice I can give you is to use meaningful names for your variables.

With that in mind, here is the solution I propose:

```py
# just for a nice output
from pprint import pprint


def find_best_prices(products, vendors):
    prices = {}

    for product_code, product_name in products:
        for vendor_product_code, vendor_phone, vendor_product_price in vendors:
            if product_code not in prices:
                prices[product_code] = {}
            if product_code == vendor_product_code:
                if prices[product_code]:
                    if prices[product_code]['price'] > vendor_product_price:
                        prices[product_code] = {
                            'vendor_price': vendor_product_price,
                            'vendor_phone': vendor_phone
                        }
                else:
                    prices[product_code] = {
                        'vendor_price': vendor_product_price,
                        'vendor_phone': vendor_phone
                    }

    return prices


products = [
    ['123456789', '2L 2% Vitali Milk'],
    ['123456798', '1L 2% Vitali Milk'],
    ['456392452', '70% Cocoa Zimbra Chocolate'],
    ['456123490', 'Zimbra Milk Chocolate'],
    ['634590221', 'Onion flavour chips'],
    ['634599011', 'Vinegar flavour chips'],
    ['780123678', 'Sliced white bread'],
    ['780432109', 'Sliced whole wheat bread'],
    ['809001234', '2L Orange Juice'],
    ['808765432', '2L Apple Juice']
]

vendors = [
    ['123456789', '7807890123', '2.58'],
    ['123456789', '7804922860', '2.99'],
    ['456392452', '7807890123', '2.11'],
    ['456123490', '7804922860', '3.10'],
    ['808765432', '7809876543', '4.10']
]

pprint(find_best_prices(products, vendors))
```

The above code will result in the following output:

```py
{'123456789': {'vendor_phone': '7807890123', 'vendor_price': '2.58'},
 '123456798': {},
 '456123490': {'vendor_phone': '7804922860', 'vendor_price': '3.10'},
 '456392452': {'vendor_phone': '7807890123', 'vendor_price': '2.11'},
 '634590221': {},
 '634599011': {},
 '780123678': {},
 '780432109': {},
 '808765432': {'vendor_phone': '7809876543', 'vendor_price': '4.10'},
 '809001234': {}}
```

The code above deals with *ties* in a *"first seen, first wins"* logic. It means that if there are two `vendors` with the same `vendor_product_price` for the same `vendor_product_code`, the first `vendor` seen goes in the report.

To change that behavior to *"last seen, last wins"*, replace `>` with `>=` in the comparison line that reads:

`if prices[product_code]['price'] > vendor_product_price:`

And finally, another strategy would be de-duplicate `vendors` based on `vendor_product_price`, keeping the minimum price, and then associate `products` with the resulting list.

Here is the implementation of that idea:

```py
def find_best_prices(products, vendors):
    prices = {}
    for product, phone, price in vendors:
        if product not in prices:
            prices[product] = {
                'vendor_phone': phone,
                'vendor_price': price
            }
        else:
            if prices[product]['vendor_price'] > price:
                prices[product] = {
                    'vendor_phone': phone,
                    'vendor_price': price
                }

    for product, _ in products:
        if product not in prices:
            prices[product] = {}

    return prices
```

There is a lot of room for improvement but that was left that way on purpose. I'm willing to be didactic, not efficient.